# Grep is not showing results even i used fgrep and -f options

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have used the below content to fetch some values .
But the `grep` in the code is not showing any results.

```
#!/bin/bash

file=test.txt

while IFS= read -r cmd;
do
    check_address=`grep -c $cmd music.cpp`
    if [ $check_address -ge 1 ]; then
        echo
    else
        grep -i -n  "$cmd" music.cpp
        echo $cmd found
    fi
done < "$file"
```

Note : there are no carriage return in my text file or `.sh` file.
i checked using

```
bash -x check.sh
```

It  is just showing

```
+grep -i -n  "$cmd" music.cpp
```

Comment: Can you show us a sample file to bring us closer to understand the issue?

Comment: This script is working fine for me, if test.txt has the commands in the file.

Comment: sorry guys thats logic problem .. i just checked ..  i changed the if and else cases in my orginal file ..

Comment: Yes, if you found 1 `$cmd` in `music.cpp`, you just `echo` which produces a blank line -- not no output `:)`

Comment: Quote `$check_address`, if it contains the result of grep.